# How to properly create a types npm package for a private feed

Tags: visual-studio, typescript, npm, asp.net-core, typescript-typings

I have a private NPM package feed I want to use for scoped packages.

I've read the [Publishing](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/publishing.html) article of the TypeScript docs. Also I tried to create the package according to the [@types/jquery](https://registry.npmjs.org/@types/jquery/-/jquery-2.0.48.tgz) package.

So this is what I came up with: Created (and published) a package with the name "@myscope/i18n". It's a pretty simple one and contains a .d.ts file with the declaration of a global interface `I18N` with the method `translate(string)`. The tarball includes the following files:

*index.d.ts*

```
/**
 * Static members of I18N
 */
interface I18NStatic {
    /**
     * Returns the translation value based on the specified key
     *
     * @param key The translation key.
    */
    translate(key: string): string;
}

declare module "i18n" {
    export = I18N;
}
declare var I18N: I18NStatic;
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "@myscope/i18n",
  "version": "1.0.11",
  "description": "TypeScript definitions for MyScope Translator",
  "license": "MIT",
  "main": "",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://myscope.visualstudio.com/example/_git/i18n"
  },
  "scripts": {},
  "dependencies": {},
  "peerDependencies": {},
  "typeScriptVersion":  "2.0" 
}
```

I consume it in a ASP.NET Core project with the following *package.json*

```
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "name": "asp.net",
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/jquery": "2.0.48",
    "@types/semantic-ui": "2.2.4",
    "@myscope/i18n": "1.0.11"
  }
}
```

But when I try to use `I18N.translate(string)` in my TS files I always get this Error

**Error TS2304  (TS) Cannot find name 'I18N'.   Example.UI.WebApp (tsconfig project)    C:\Users\Sandro\Source\Repos\example\Example.UI.WebApp\TypeScript\Address.ts**

When I use index.d.ts directly in my project (not via npm) it works perfectly. But as soon as I delete it again, it stops working. I have no errors or warnings in the "Dependencies/npm" section of the project in solution explorer view.

What am I missing?

Comment: Try to specify _typeRoots_ in consuming _tsconfig_: `"typeRoots": [ "node_modules/@types", "node_modules/@myscope"]`

Comment: Sadly this didn't do the trick